# Regex Full Match vs. Group Matches in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

The following extracts **UDP** as Group 3.

**([0-9A-F]{2}){5}([0-9A-F]{6}.)(\b[A-Z]{3})**

The following extracts **Q** as Group 3.

**(\d+[abc]+\s{3})(\b[A-Z])**

The following extracts **A** or **SOA** as Group 2.

**(]+\s)(\b[A-Z])**

```
7/26/2020 11:59:20 PM 2C0C PACKET  00000137F00E6B40 UDP Rcv 192.168.2.182   994c   Q [0001   D   NOERROR] A      (8)metadata(6)google(8)internal(0)
7/26/2020 11:59:20 PM 2B10 PACKET  00000121F00F92A0 UDP Rcv 127.0.0.1       1617   Q [0001   D   NOERROR] SOA    (6)_msdcs(6)microsoft(3)com(0)
7/26/2020 11:59:20 PM 24BC PACKET  0000019926F82050 UDP Rcv 192.168.10.20   5e0e   Q [0001   D   NOERROR] A      (4)wpad(5)win(2)jp(7)google(3)com(0)
7/26/2020 11:59:20 PM 1464 PACKET  00000192F00E6880 UDP Rcv 127.0.0.1       9937   Q [0001   D   NOERROR] SOA    (36)f4f036d7-238e-43a9-98f8-a76594be9ed9(6)_msdcs(6)yahoo(3)com(0)
```

How can each of these regex's be improved so that it's a full match for each regex expression?

Comment: Are you asking how to combine the regexes into a single regex to extract the 'UDP', 'Q' and 'A' parts from your data example with Python? Given that there's some redundancy in your expression, it's unclear what exactly you are matching - it would probably be helpful if you provided a few more, clearly different lines of example data.

Comment: If all you care about is "UDP", "Q", and "A", you shouldn't use capturing groups for anything else. You could use `[0-9A-F]{16}\s([A-Z]{3}).*\d+[abc]+\s{3}([A-Z]).*]+\s([A-Z])`. Here's a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/FRyiRR/1).

Comment: Based on your edit, you probably want `[0-9A-F]{16}\s([A-Z]{3}).*[a-f0-9]+\s{3}([A-Z]).*]+\s(A|SOA)` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/FRyiRR/2)). The question is not clear though. You should have clear rules for matching.

Comment: Are you really sure you _have_ to use regex there? Won't it be simpler to just use `.split()` and index the locations directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first expression:

```
([0-9A-F]{2}){5}([0-9A-F]{6}.)(\b[A-Z]{3})
```

Seems to match 2 * 5 hexadecimal characters, followed by 6 of them (so 16 total), followed by any single character, and then matching three capitals after a word boundary. However, it would appear that you really just expect there to be a whitespace character between the 16 hex chars and the protocol. So you could just match the first group from:

```
(?:[0-9A-F]{16})\s([A-Z]{3})
```

Similarly, to get 'Q' (or any character in its position) and 'A' or 'SOA', you could say it's the last series of `[A-Z]` before the first `[` and the first series of `[A-Z]` after the first `]`.

The whole expression then becomes:

```
(?:[0-9A-F]{16})\s([A-Z]{3}).*([A-Z]+)\s\[.*?\]\s([A-Z]+)
```

From which you'll need groups 1, 2 and 3. In python:

```
import re

lines = [
    '7/26/2020 11:59:20 PM 2C0C PACKET  00000137F00E6B40 UDP Rcv 192.168.2.182   994c   Q [0001   D   NOERROR] A      (8)metadata(6)google(8)internal(0)',
    '7/26/2020 11:59:20 PM 2B10 PACKET  00000121F00F92A0 UDP Rcv 127.0.0.1       1617   Q [0001   D   NOERROR] SOA    (6)_msdcs(6)microsoft(3)com(0)',
    '7/26/2020 11:59:20 PM 24BC PACKET  0000019926F82050 UDP Rcv 192.168.10.20   5e0e   Q [0001   D   NOERROR] A      (4)wpad(5)win(2)jp(7)google(3)com(0)',
    '7/26/2020 11:59:20 PM 1464 PACKET  00000192F00E6880 UDP Rcv 127.0.0.1       9937   Q [0001   D   NOERROR] SOA    (36)f4f036d7-238e-43a9-98f8-a76594be9ed9(6)_msdcs(6)yahoo(3)com(0)'
]

rgx = re.compile(r'.*?(?:[0-9A-F]{16})\s([A-Z]{3}).*([A-Z]+)\s\[.*?\]\s([A-Z]+).*')
for line in lines:
    match = rgx.match(line)
    if not match:
        print('Something is wrong')
    else:
        print(match.group(1), match.group(2), match.group(3))
```

Result:

```
UDP Q A
UDP Q SOA
UDP Q A
UDP Q SOA
```

As pointed out by @41686d6564, you can leave out the non-capturing group:

```
rgx = re.compile(r'.*?[0-9A-F]{16}\s([A-Z]{3}).*([A-Z]+)\s\[.*?\]\s([A-Z]+).*')
```

Also, if you just have all the content as a single block of text, this is a concise way to go about it:

```
import re

lines = '7/26/2020 11:59:20 PM 2C0C PACKET  00000137F00E6B40 UDP Rcv 192.168.2.182   994c   Q [0001   D   NOERROR] A      (8)metadata(6)google(8)internal(0)\n' \
        '7/26/2020 11:59:20 PM 2B10 PACKET  00000121F00F92A0 UDP Rcv 127.0.0.1       1617   Q [0001   D   NOERROR] SOA    (6)_msdcs(6)microsoft(3)com(0)\n' \
        '7/26/2020 11:59:20 PM 24BC PACKET  0000019926F82050 UDP Rcv 192.168.10.20   5e0e   Q [0001   D   NOERROR] A      (4)wpad(5)win(2)jp(7)google(3)com(0)\n' \
        '7/26/2020 11:59:20 PM 1464 PACKET  00000192F00E6880 UDP Rcv 127.0.0.1       9937   Q [0001   D   NOERROR] SOA    (36)f4f036d7-238e-43a9-98f8-a76594be9ed9(6)_msdcs(6)yahoo(3)com(0)'


rgx = re.compile(r'[0-9A-F]{16}\s([A-Z]{3}).*([A-Z]+)\s\[.*?\]\s([A-Z]+)')
for match in rgx.findall(lines):
    print(match[0], match[1], match[2])
```

Comment: The non-capturing group is redundant here.

Comment: thank you grismar for breaking it down.  i learned something today.